# iPhone Web Application

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I had a quick question regarding `UIWebView`.  Is there anyway to programmatically navigate the `UIWebView`?  Essentially, I prompt the user for certain information, such as (Current Location, Time).  Using this information, I would like to fill out and complete a form on a webpage, and display the resulting `UIWebView` to the user.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to control the UIWebView using the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method.  For example you should be able to insert text into an input and submit a form:

```
NSString* script = @"document.getElementById('Name').value = 'Hello'; document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();";
[self.web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

You'd have to customize the JavaScript to do whatever you want.  For example, you could inject values that you had collected into the script, then run the JavaScript.

You could hide the UIWebView until the new page had loaded, then show it to the user.

Come to think of it, it'd be nice if there were a Selenium type wrapper around the web view, but I don't know of anything like that right now.